# Extracting hashtags using Tweepy to go into MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, tweepy

I'm a complete programming noob, and am trying to configure a Twitter-Tweepy-MySQL collection mechanism.  I've reviewed a bunch of similar posts about this and I can't quite get an answer, so I hope I'm not duplicating here ...

I'm happy with the basic script I've got running, and I'm now trying to refine it to build the exact schema I'm after.

I've spent several frustrating hours trying to sort out the hashtag extraction.  I can extract a hashtag ok - the problem is a tweet often has half a dozen, and I need them all.  My issue is that they're part of an array in the Tweet object, and I can't quite work out how to tell Python to extract them all and populate MySQL.  I'm pretty sure I need to use one of the conditionals, but can't make TRY or IF work on each hashtag line ...

Try not to laugh when you look at my script, below - I know it's incredibly amateurish, but YouTube can only take you so far.  I hope it's obvious what I'm trying to do, and I'll leave the comments in to show some of my previous attempts / thinking.

Very grateful for any advice!  Robin

Script follows:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import MySQLdb
import time
import json

conn = MySQLdb.connect("snarf","snarf","snarf","snarf", charset='utf8')

c = conn.cursor()

#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey = 'snarf'
csecret = 'snarf'
atoken = 'snarf'
asecret = 'snarf'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(data)

            screen_name = tweet["user"]["screen_name"]
            created_at = tweet ["created_at"]
            identity = tweet ["id"]
            text = tweet ["text"]

            hashtag1 = tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"][0]["text"]
            #hashtag2 = tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"][1]["text"]
            #hashtag3 = tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"][2]["text"]
            #hashtag4 = tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"][3]["text"]
            #hashtag5 = tweet ["entities"]["hashtags"][4]["text"]

            #URL1 = tweet ["entities"]["urls"][0]["expanded_url"]
            #URL2 = tweet ["entities"]["urls"][1]["expanded_url"]
            #URL3 = tweet ["entities"]["urls"][2]["expanded_url"]
            #URL4 = tweet ["entities"]["urls"][3]["expanded_url"]
            #URL5 = tweet ["entities"]["urls"][4]["expanded_url"]

                   c.execute("INSERT INTO news (timestamp, screen_name, created_at, id, text, hashtag_1) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                (time.time(), screen_name, created_at, identity, text, hashtag1))

            conn.commit()

            print((text))

            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on data,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["#football", "#soccer"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop like this:

```
hashtags = []   #make an empty list

for hashtag in tweet["entities"]["hashtags"]:    #iterate over the list
    hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])             #append each hashtag to 'hashtags'

 c.execute("INSERT INTO news (timestamp, screen_name, created_at, id, text, hashtag_1) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (time.time(), screen_name, created_at, identity, text, str(hashtags)))
```

It simply goes through the list of hashtags and appends the text to a list called 'hashtags'. Because I don't know any way to store a list of undefined length in a  SQL database, I basically convert (serialized) the list to a string using `str()` and store it in the column hashtag_1.

If you are looking for a more detailed python course: I really enjoyed [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com)

**EDIT:**

If the tweet contains single quotes, the text will be saved only partially. Subsequently you should put the following code in front of the for loop:

```
#I presume your tweet is saved in the variable text
txt = []
if "'" in text:
    for item in text:
        if not item=="'":
            txt.append(item)
        else:
            txt.append("''")
    text = ''.join(txt)
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Markus, many thanks for this!  I'll have a look into your suggestion now and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: the Python bit works perfectly, but now MySQL is complaining about syntax.  I'll have a play and see if I can get it to work - thank you!

Comment: Is the column 'timestamp' an 'INT' or  a string?

Comment: It was an INT.  I changed it to VARCHAR(45), but no dice.  Besides, I couldn't get MySQL to change the primary key column to a string, so we couldn't have had all the values being written as strings.  

BUT: I modified your code slightly to ... 

'((time.time()), screen_name, created_at, identity, text, str(hashtags)))'

... and it works!  

I have a lot more tinkering to do (eg my hashtag column now has entries like "[u'Football', u'Basketball', u'Cadets']", whereas ideally I'd like multiple columns containing clean hashtags), but that's a major obstacle overcome.  MANY thanks, Markus!

Comment: I'm glad, I could help! I have added another thing you should watch out for to the post. Let me know, If there are any problems with the code or SQL...